# A property of Unitary operators

Tags: linear-algebra

Let U be an unitary operator. If $(U-I)^n (x)=0$ then $(U-I)(x)=0$.

It will be enough if you help me with $n=2$.

I tried to apply the adjoint of U to $(U-I)^2(x) \implies (U+U^t)(x)=2x $. I am not sure if it is useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because $U$ is unitary, we know that $U$ is normal, and thus $U - I$ is also normal. As is well known, if $T$ is normal, then the null space of $T^n$ equals the null space of $T$, giving the desired result.

This proof shows that the hypothesis that $U$ is unitary can be replaced by the much weaker hypothesis that $U$ is normal.